# Is it possible to break execution on any transition to my code?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I need to break execution when my code is hit, that is effectively putting breakpoint on every code line. But I want to activate it after I started the execution of the application.

Is there a straightforward way to achieve it?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a feature. Don't you know where the entry point is or what function will be called?

Comment: multiple of background services, so yes, not clear, which is called when

Comment: The "Breakpoints" Window has a feature to set function breakpoints (try the "New..." button). Maybe this allows wildcards? Is this for .NET or native?

Comment: It is for .NET Thanks, I'll check.

Answer (score 1):

My [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) extension can show when and how your code is hit during the execution of the application.